# How to resize PNG image file without altering its dimension in iOS?

Tags: ios

How to change the size of the PNG image without altering its dimensions in iOS? Is it possible in iOS? we have default method to achieve this but it is applicable for JPEG images only, is there any default compression method to compress the PNG image file?

Comment: Do you want to change the actual size of the image, or do you just want that it is displayed smaller in your application?

Comment: I want to change its actual  size.

Comment: For example, I've an image of size 1MB with dimension 320*120 I want it to be converted to size< 1MB with the same dimension 320*120.

Comment: Unlike JPG, there is no API to change the compression level of PNG. So no, you can't create a PNG with a smaller file size without changing its dimensions.

Comment: Keep in mind that PNG is a lossless image format. JPG is not which is why JPG images can be compress more and more at the expense of quality.

Answer (score 3):

```
 CGFloat compression = 0.5f;
CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
int maxFileSize = 250*1024;

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thmImageView.image, compression);

while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
{
    compression -= 0.1;
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thmImageView.image, compression);
}UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

you will get compressed image size upto 20-40kb. its applicable for png also try once.